# mount: permission deined - ISPConfig 3

Tags: mount, apache2

I’m currently trying to install ISPCONFIG while running "mount -o remount /" it said "mount: permission deined". My fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/belzar-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,usrjquota=quota.user,grpjquota=quota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=46d1bd79-d761-4b23-80b8-ad20cb18e049 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/belzar-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0

    proc  /proc       proc    defaults    0    0
    none  /dev/pts    devpts  rw,gid=5,mode=620    0    0
    none  /run/shm    tmpfs   defaults    0    0
```

[Here](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-debian-wheezy-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p4) is link on tutorial (**14 Install PureFTPd And Quota**).